# Crashing at a specific view part

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been working on this view at the moment learned a lot and been stuck for sometime. This screen (view) is crashing when i add the commented code section, which I don't know why but I need it there because it's a component of the view.

**Documentos.xaml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:AppQ4evo.Models"
             x:Class="AppQ4evo.Views.Documentos" 
             BackgroundColor="White">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:DocumentsBindingModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="iconAttach" Order="Primary" Icon="attach.png" Priority="-1" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid x:Name="docs" Padding="-2" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,20">
                        <Label Text="Data Documento: "/>
                        <Label Text="Número externo: "/>
                        <Label Text="Fornecedor: "/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,-10">
                        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Text="Adicionar" Clicked="btnAddPopup_Clicked" />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <!--
                    <Grid x:Name="ListViewHeaders" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <BoxView Color="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" HeightRequest="0.5" />
                        <BoxView Color="DimGray"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Produto" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Descrição" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="Observação" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="Qtd" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="5" Text="Valor Unitário" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="6" Text="IVA" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="absLayout" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <ListView x:Name="DocumentsList" ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentosList}" HasUnevenRows="True" Margin="0,60" BackgroundColor="White" 
                        HeightRequest="{Binding Path=Height, Source={x:Reference absLayout}}" WidthRequest="{Binding Path=Width, Source={x:Reference absLayout}}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <ViewCell.View>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="45"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Produto}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Descricao}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Observacao}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Quantidade}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding ValorUnitario}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding Iva}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ViewCell.View>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                    -->
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
            <ContentView x:Name="popupAddDocumentView" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Margin="40,120" Padding="10,0" IsVisible="false" >
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                        <Image HorizontalOptions="End" Source="close.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnImageNameTapped_ClosePopup" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                        <Entry x:Name="ProdutoEntry" Margin="20,0,20,0" Placeholder="Introduza o produto" />
                        <Entry x:Name="DescricaoEntry" Margin="20,0,20,0" Placeholder="Introduza a descrição" />
                        <Entry x:Name="ObservacaoEntry" Margin="20,0,20,0" Placeholder="Introduza a observação" />
                        <Entry x:Name="QuantidadeEntry" Margin="20,0,20,0" Placeholder="Introduza a quantidade" />
                        <Entry x:Name="ValorUnitarioEntry" Margin="20,0,20,0" Placeholder="Introduza o valor" />
                        <Entry x:Name="IvaEntry" Margin="20,0,20,0" Placeholder="Introduza o IVA" />
                        <Button x:Name="btnAddDocument" Margin="20,0,20,0" Clicked="btnAddDocument_Clicked" Text="Adicionar" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Documentos.xaml.cs code:**

```
using AppQ4evo.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace AppQ4evo.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Documentos : ContentPage
    {

        DocumentsBindingModel documents;

        public Documentos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            documents = new DocumentsBindingModel();
        }

        private void btnAddPopup_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Olá Tren");
            popupAddDocumentView.IsVisible = true;
        }

        private void OnImageNameTapped_ClosePopup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                popupAddDocumentView.IsVisible = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        private void btnAddDocument_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            popupAddDocumentView.IsVisible = false;
            DocumentosModel documentosBindingModel = new DocumentosModel() { Produto = ProdutoEntry.Text };
            documents.DocumentosList.Add(documentosBindingModel);

            BindingContext = documents;
            //DocumentsList.IsRefreshing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to know what is causing it and how to fix it? Because I don't know how to go around when I have problems like this.

I have commented some parts and it shows them individually but when I uncomment everything to make it work as one it feels like it puts to much effort on the app and it crashes.

Comment: What is the exception causing the crash?  Have you tried selectively commenting the layout to find the problem?  Right now you have two very big sections commented, you should be able to narrow it down

Comment: There is no exception, i press to go to that view and it says the app isn't responding.
 
Caught this one console -  "[View] requestLayout() improperly called by crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer".

The sections i have comment (Grid and Absolute Layout) work fine if I comment the ContentView in the end or vice-versa. But if i have the 3 sections uncomment it just doesn't open the view.

Comment: Replace the ContentView with a layout might be an option. Or delete the ContentView tag for testing first.

Comment: It's the 1st AbsoluteLayout that's making the crash, found it!